# plotting cox proportional hazard model in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot a cox proportional hazard model in R. (or a logit model)
I used the following code (which I copied from https://sites.google.com/site/daishizuka/toolkits/plotting-logistic-regression-in-r)

```
c<-coxph(formula=Surv(year, promo)~prov.yrs, data=cul)
curve(predict(c, data.frame(prov.yrs=x), type="risk"), add=TRUE)
```

I get the error message

```
Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : 
  invalid graphics state
```

I believe there is something wrong with plotting this, so I was wondering if there is a way to plot this. I get the same error message when I use glm. Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Example runs for me... R 3.0.1 W7 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

The example you copied from shows a logistic regression, but you are fitting a coxph model, they are very different in how they are handled.

If you just want a plot of the the hazard ratio then your code will basically work (except you are adding to a plot that is not there, which may be what generates the error, try changing `add` to `FALSE`).

If you want to plot the survival curve(s) then use the `survfit` function to get the predicted survival information and plot that.

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests you did not have a device open or perhaps there was some other problem with the plot you were trying to add to? That code produces a plot over a range input [0,1] with a toy example I built from the `coxph` help page. Perhaps your range for the 'prov.yrs' is different than an existing plot, or there is no device open? Try `plot.new()`, plot whatever else you were going to use, and then rerun? (The add=TRUE will suppress plotting of the box, axes and labels.)